# Why are static and dynamic resource changes not reflected in customized Portal 8.0 theme?

Tags: jsp, themes, websphere, portal, websphere-portal

I'm working with a Portal 8.0.0.1 on my Windows 7 machine and have followed steps to create a customized theme that is based on the Portal 8.0 theme.  I've set all the properties that I think are needed in order to allow me to make edits to the html and JSP files which can then be recognized by the portal without having to restart the theme app or the portal, but it is not working.   I'm trying to understand what I might have missed during the customization process.

I followed the steps described in both places here: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Deploying_and_developing_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_8_themes_A_step-by-step_guide

and here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Websphere%20Portal%208%20WIKI

Those instructions are essentially identical, but I'm not sure which set is the original; I also found a PDF file of the same instructions.  The instructions are great, have a lot of detailed steps, but were lacking in a couple of places that has me questioning the integrity of my new customized theme.   The instructions assume 2 things that I could not realize:

1. I am using RAD.
2. The sample XML access file for registering the theme with the portal is attached.

The instructions depend on RAD for one main step that I could not reproduce with Eclipse - the creation of the ibm-web-ext.xmi and the ibm-web-bnd.xmi files.   These are IBM files and only RAD will create them.  I had to locate copies of those files from other projects and try to customize them for the Static and Dynamic Eclipse projects created in these instructions.  I'm aware that the ibm-web-ext.xmi file is the key to allowing JSP reloading via the "reloadingEnabled" property, so I made sure to enable that property as instructed.  In addition to that setting the instructions note that this line needs to be added to the Dynamic project's Default.jsp file:

```
--%><r:param name="max-age" value="2"/>
```

so I made sure to add that line.

The contents of the Static project's ibm-web-bnd.xmi file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_FpmTheme8Static" virtualHostName="default_host">
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
</webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

and the contents of the Static project's ibm-web-ext.xmi file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappext:WebAppExtension xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappext="webappext.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppExtension_FpmTheme8Static" reloadInterval="3" reloadingEnabled="true" additionalClassPath="" fileServingEnabled="true" directoryBrowsingEnabled="false" serveServletsByClassnameEnabled="false" preCompileJSPs="false">
  <webApp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
</webappext:WebAppExtension>
```

and the contents of the Dynamic project's ibm-web-bnd.xmi file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_FpmTheme8Dynamic" virtualHostName="default_host">
  <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
</webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

and the contents of the Dynamic project's ibm-web-ext.xmi file is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappext:WebAppExtension xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappext="webappext.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppExtension_FpmTheme8Dynamic" reloadInterval="3" reloadingEnabled="true" additionalClassPath="" fileServingEnabled="true" directoryBrowsingEnabled="false" serveServletsByClassnameEnabled="false" preCompileJSPs="false">
  <webApp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
</webappext:WebAppExtension>
```

Do those look valid?  Are there any other locations that need to have some configuration set in order to allow JSP reloading?

The second issue with the instructions is that the sample XML access file was not attached.  I created one as best I could and it looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- IBM WebSphere Portal/8.0.0.1 build wp8001CF12_001_15 exported on Mon Apr 20 22:51:09 EDT 2015 from BF904V1/192.168.7.89 -->
<request build="wp8001CF12_001_15" type="update" version="8.0.0.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_8.0.0.xsd">
    <portal action="locate">
        <skin action="update" active="true" context-root="/FpmTheme8" default="true" domain="rel"  resourceroot="Hidden" type="default" uniquename="FpmThem8.Hidden">
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>FPM Theme8 - Hidden</title>
            </localedata>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skintype" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[template]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.file.name.html" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[skin.html]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.ref" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:FpmTheme8Static/themes/Portal8.0/skins/Hidden/]]></parameter>
        </skin>
        <skin action="update" active="true" context-root="/FpmTheme8" default="false" domain="rel" resourceroot="Standard" type="default" uniquename="FpmTheme8.Standard">
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>FPM Theme8 - Standard</title>
            </localedata>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skintype" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[template]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.file.name.html" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[skin.html]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.ref" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:FpmTheme8Static/themes/Portal8.0/skins/Standard/]]></parameter>
        </skin>
        <skin action="update" active="true" context-root="/FpmTheme8" default="false" domain="rel" resourceroot="NoSkin" type="default" uniquename="FpmTheme8.NoSkin">
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>FPM Theme8 - No Skin</title>
            </localedata>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skintype" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[template]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.file.name.html" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[skin.html]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.ref" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:FpmTheme8Static/themes/Portal8.0/skins/NoSkin/]]></parameter>
        </skin>
        <theme action="update" active="true" context-root="/FpmTheme8" default="false" domain="rel" resourceroot="dynamicSpots" uniquename="FpmTheme8">
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>FPM THEME8</title>
            </localedata>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.theme.dnd.sources" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[ibmDndColumn:com.ibm.pb.dnd.layout.LayoutColumnSource:vertical,ibmDndRow:com.ibm.pb.dnd.layout.LayoutRowSource:horizontal]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="ibm.portal.shelf.category.json.socialrendering" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[system/SocialCategory.json,label:shelf_communicationsCategory]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.layout.template.href" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:FpmTheme8Static/themes/Portal8.0/layout-templates/1Column/]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.theme.aggregationmodes" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[ssa]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="resourceaggregation.profile" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[profiles/profile_full.json]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.theme.template.ref" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:FpmTheme8Static/themes/Portal8.0/]]></parameter>
        </theme>
    </portal>
    <status element="all" result="ok"/>
</request>
```

I remember in earlier installations I had already set the "resourceaggregation.development.mode" property (of the WP ConfigService resource environment provider) to true as instructed prior to copying the static resources from the Portal 8.0 theme - so that's the only other configuration that I think might be remotely related to this issue.

I've assigned this custom theme to some pages already and they look like they're behaving correctly.  I don't see any functional or behavioral issues with the use of this new custom theme, but I simply can't get the JSP reloading to work as needed.

Do you have any suggestion on what I should look at to debug this?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question to IBM, opening a PMR ticket with them.  I sent them the packaged EAR file for them to review.   They deployed that EAR file into their Portal8.0.0.1/CF16 environment but were not able to reproduce the problem - but when they deployed it into their Portal8.0.0.1/**CF12** environment, they were seeing the same problem.  Their suggestion was to upgrade from CF12 to CF16.   Upgrading is not an option for our project right now, so I explored the alternative option of trying to deploy the custom theme as a single WAR file in hopes of that working.  I based my attempt on the instructions at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Create_a_custom_theme_without_WebDAV_with_8.0 and eventually succeeded in deploying the new custom theme in a single WAR file, and then the JSP reloading worked for both static and dynamic resources.  It's not the perfect solution I was looking for, as IBM encouraged the EAR solution going forward with CF16, but it is currently working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for Portal 8.5, I hope it helps someone who reach here. In my case, I was trying to reload the jsps in a Theme without deploying.
@okorng your files seems ok, but you miss the jsp-attributes:

```
<jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>
<jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="3"/>
```

I use an xml instead of a xmi, but you can see an example here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tweb_jspengine.html

This is my final ibm-web-ext.xml (in dynamic and static proyects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1">

    <jsp-attribute name="reloadEnabled" value="true"/>
    <jsp-attribute name="reloadInterval" value="3"/>

    <reload-interval value="3"/>
    <context-root uri="/wps/XXX_Theme" />
    <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
    <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
    <enable-reloading value="true"/>
    <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />
</web-ext>
```

Be carefoul, reloadInterval must has the same value that reload-interval or the theme will not be deployed :)